# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str in Flask App

Tags: python, flask

I am getting error `list indices must be integers, not str` during the iteration of list `meters_info`. Why I am getting such error?
Thanks Guys pointing me out, Original application is in **django** and I am converting it to flask app. In django they are `datastructures.SortedDict`. How I use same functionality in flask
   [See this link](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/api/ceilometer.py#L928-L940)

```
from django.utils import datastructures
meters_info = datastructures.SortedDict([
            ("instance", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Existence of instance"),
            }),
            ("instance:<type>", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Existence of instance <type> "
                                 "(openstack types)"),
            }),
            ("memory", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Volume of RAM"),
            }),])
```

**Flask App**

```
def _get_nova_meters_info(self):
        meters_info= [
            ("instance", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance",
            }),
            ("instance:<type>", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance <type> (openstack types)",
            }),
            ("memory", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Volume of RAM",
            }),]
```

Getting message in console

```
File "/home/vagrant/api/ceilometer.py", line 137, in _get_nova_meters_info

meters_info[name]=dict(meters_info["instance:<type>"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Please see the following method where I am getting error

```
for flavor in self.get_flavor_names():
            name='instance:%s' %flavor
            meters_info[name]=dict(meters_info["instance:<type>"])

            meters_info[name]['description']= (
                'Duration of instance type %s (openstack flavor)' % flavor)
        return meters_info


def get_flavor_names(self):
        return ['m1.tiny', 'm1.small', 'm1.medium', 'm1.large', 'm1.nano','m1.xlarge', 'm1.micro']
```

Comment: `meters_info` is a list, not a dict. Notice that the first part of the `meters_info` definiton is `[`, which is the syntax for a list. Even stranger, it's a list of tuples that contain dicts. I think it should be a dictionary of dictionaries but your data structure is unclear. Why is it laid out this way?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Please see updated quesitonThis is the django app and I am converting it to flask app. In django they are using `_(` I think this is for translation I don't want to use it right now. Have a look on this link https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/api/ceilometer.py#L928-L940

Comment: I'm a little confused. In the Django form it wraps the data in a `SortedDict` (which is similar to a regular dictionary) but in your code you removed the part that converts to a `SortedDict`. Can you make further changes to the data structure (like using a dictionary as the answers have suggested) or does it have to remain in the format you've put here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of tuples containing dictionaries. That can't be accessed with strings, you'd need to use integers. The original Django app used a special type of Django dictionary called `SortedDict`, thankfully Python has had an equivalent called `OrderedDict` since 2.7. You just need to import it like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

And then adjust your syntax to use `OrderedDict` and remove the `_()` around the values:

```
meters_info = OrderedDict([
            ("instance", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance",
            }),
            ("instance:<type>", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance <type> "
                                 "(openstack types)",
            }),
            ("memory", {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Volume of RAM",
            }),])
```

Answer (score 1):

To use data in such way you need to rebuild meter_info to dictionary:

```
        meters_info= {
            "instance" : {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance",
            },
            "instance:<type>" : {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Existence of instance <type> (openstack types)",
            }, 
            "memory" : {
                'label': '',
                'description': "Volume of RAM",
            },}
```

also it's is better if you have same structure to use classes. For example

```
        class Meters_info_param_stucture(object):
            def __init__(self, label = None, description = None):
                self.label = label
                self.description = description

        meters_info= {
            "instance" : Meters_info_param_stucture(description = "Existence of instance"),
            "instance:<type>" : Meters_info_param_stucture(description = "Existence of instance <type> (openstack types)"),
            "memory" : Meters_info_param_stucture(description = "Volume of RAM"),}

        >>>meters_info["memory"].description
        'Volume of RAM'
```

Comment: Or maybe he will need to define a separate class.

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi Please see the updated questions .

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi This is the django app and I am converting it to flask app. In django they are using `_(` I think this is for translation I don't want to use it right now. Have a look on this link https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/api/ceilometer.py#L928-L940

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array is a `list` of `tuple`s, and a `tuple` has a `str` as the first element, and `dict` as the second. So you should access it like this:

```
meters_info[0][0][<some_key>]
```

For example:

```
meters_info[0][0]["instance"]
```

But I do not understand the structure and the reason you keep it like that. You should rather consider reorganising `meters_info` into a dictionary, like [***Dmitry.Samborskyi suggests***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939919/3264192).

Comment: Please see updated quesitonThis is the django app and I am converting it to flask app. In django they are using `_(` I think this is for translation I don't want to use it right now. Have a look on this link https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/api/ceilometer.py#L928-L940